# How to create a bucket policy with sourceIP restriction for S3 Access Log target bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have created one S3 bucket and have enabled server access logging. There is another S3 bucket which is the target bucket for server access log delivery of the first bucket I mentioned.

Now there is a requirement to keep sourceIP restriction on the target bucket's policy, so the policy on the target bucket is somewhat as below -

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1234567890",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow-only-specific-sourceIPs",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::log-target-bucket-xyz",
                "arn:aws:s3:::log-target-bucket-xyz/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "10.0.0.1",
                        "10.0.0.2"
                    ]
                },
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "aws:sourceVpce": "vpce-1234xyz",
                    "aws:username": "xyz-user"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But with this policy the server access logs aren't getting delivered to the bucket. This policy is supposed to allow S3 actions to only the source IPs, vpc endpoints and username in condition.

The target bucket has following ACL also:

```
{
       "Grantee": {
            "Type": "Group",
            "URI": "http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/s3/LogDelivery"
        },
        "Permission": "WRITE"
    },
    {
        "Grantee": {
            "Type": "Group",
            "URI": "http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/s3/LogDelivery"
        },
        "Permission": "READ_ACP"
    }
```

The Problem is: The S3 server **access logs are not getting generated** and I need to keep the sourceIP, vpce restriction on the target bucket. The problem resolves If I remove the restrictions from bucket policy. But can't seem to find a solution to have logs generated with the restrictions.

Edit:
Tried the following condition, but didn't work:

```
"StringNotLikeIfExists": {
  "s3:x-amz-grant-write": "acs.amazonaws.com/groups/s3/LogDelivery"
}
```

Please let me know if anyone has any solution or suggestions to solve this problem. Any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your policy should be a combination if **NotIpAddressIfExists** and **StringNotEqualsIfExists** conditions as described in :

```
    {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Id": "Policy1234567890",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Sid": "Allow-only-specific-sourceIPs",
                "Effect": "Deny",
                "Principal": "*",
                "Action": "s3:*",
                "Resource": [
                    "arn:aws:s3:::log-target-bucket-xyz",
                    "arn:aws:s3:::log-target-bucket-xyz/*"
                ],
                "Condition": {
                    "NotIpAddressIfExists": {
                        "aws:SourceIp": [
                            "10.0.0.1",
                            "10.0.0.2"
                        ]
                    },
                    "StringNotEqualsIfExists": {
                        "aws:sourceVpce": "vpce-1234xyz",
                        "aws:username": "xyz-user"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

This is very well explained in this question's [s3-bucket-security-open-access-restricted-by-public-ip-and-vpc-endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36413759/s3-bucket-security-open-access-restricted-by-public-ip-and-vpc-endpoint)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however just want to clarify the problem I'm facing is that S3 server access logs aren't getting generated in the bucket. These logs are generated by S3 Log Delivery Group as per AWS docs, so I'm guessing that putting sourceIp and vpce restrictions is not allowing the Log Delivery Group to put the log files into the bucket. This is what I need to resolve. Besides this problem, the sourceIp and vpce restrictions are working fine.

Comment: I am not sure if you time to go through the explanation of the conditions, and I understood your problem, so as you can see in the policy I just changed the conditions. explanation: When defining policies, if the request is coming through a VPC Endpoint, source IP key is not available. Similarly, if the request is coming outside of VPC endpoint, VPC related keys are not available. IfExists needs to be used to evaluate keys that are conditionally available.

In your policy you are always checking for the conditions, with conditions I amended they are checked only if they are present.

Comment: Okay, I have understood what you are suggesting and incorporated the changes. But still my problem is not yet solved. The logs are not getting generated. Thanks for your explanation @samtoddler .